# Julia pass optional parameter to inner function call

Tags: julia

I have something like the following

```
function test(; testvar=nothing)
   # only pass testvar to function if it has a useful value
   inner_function(testvar != nothing ? testvar2=testvar : # leave it out)
end

# library function, outside my control, testvar2 can't be nothing
function inner_function(; testvar2=useful value)
   # do something
end
```

I know I can use if/else statements within `test()` but `inner_function` has lots of parameters so I would prefer to avoid that from a code duplication standpoint. Is this possible?

**Note:** `inner_function` *cannot* have `testvar2 = nothing`, if `testvar2` is passed it has to have a valid value.

Comment: You could put the variables into an array or dictionary and filter out `nothing`. Is that the kind of thing you mean?

Comment: How do I then pass these to `inner_function` as keyword=argument pairs? Because that's what I would like to achieve.

Comment: @Higany You can use `...` to pass keyword arguments, like `inner_function(;filter((x,y)->y!=nothing, args)...)`

Comment: What is `args` in your example?

Comment: Why not use multiple dispatch?

`test(x::Nothing)`

`test(x::Useful)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @elsuizo points out, multiple dispatch is one of the core julia features which allows you to perform such operations. Find bellow a quick example:

```
>>> inner_func(x) = true;
>>> inner_func(::Type{Void}) = false;
```

Note: it seems `Nothing` has been renamed to `Void` (as a warning prompts out when I try to use it).

`inner_func` has 2 method definitions, if `Void` is passed as a parameter, the function will just return `false` (change this behaviour by *do nothing* or whatever you want to do). Instead, if the function receives anything else than `Void`, it will just do something else (in this case, return `true`).

Your `test` wouldn't have to perform any check at all. Just pass the parameters to the `inner_func`, and it will decide what to do (which of the 2 methods of the function `inner_func` to call) depending on the parameter type.

An example:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, Void, 5];
>>> filter(inner_func, a)
4-element Array{Any,1}:
 1
 2
 3
 5
```

For the numerical elements, the function calls the method of the function that returns `true`, and thus, the numerical elements are returned. For the `Void` element, the second method of the function is called, returning `false`, and thus, not returning such element.